# Можно ли выяснить присвоено ли значение переменной C++

Tags: c++

Код описывающий мою проблему:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int a[size];
    a[0] = 5;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << (a[i] == empty() ? 0 : a[i]);
}
```

Функция `empty()` - какая либо проверка на проинициализированность переменной. Можно ли выяснить каким либо образом, что переменной присвоили значение без использования нижних границ (то бишь, если в массиве должны положительные числа то элемента массива можно проинициализировать нулями)?

Comment: Там вообще мусор, что угодно - и как вы хотите **это** проверять?... Нет, только инициализация заведомо неиспользуемым значением - если таковое есть.

Comment: В данном случае все элементы массива автоматически проинициализированы. При выделении памяти ячейки массива заполняются мусором.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Массив `a` не инициализирован. Стандарт прямо запрещает читать неинициализированные данные. Следовательно, у вас нет законного способа проверить есть там что-то или нет (в отличие от JavaScript с его `undefined`).

Но можно сделать так: `int a[size] = {0};`. Это специальная нотация, которая заполнит массив нулями. Теперь вы можете проверять его ячейки до присваивания значений элементам.

Пара замечаний вдогонку:

`int a[size] = {0};` это действительно специальная нотация. Например `int a[size] = {1};` не будет заполнять всё единицами, а заполнит первый элемент единицей, а остальные нулями. Ноль можно опустить в C++ (в C нельзя): `int a[size] = {};` - всё будет заполнено нулями.

Ничего стандарт не запрещает конечно. Обращение к неинициализированной переменной порождает [неопределённое поведение (undefined behaviour)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). То есть, авторы стандарта не знают что будет делать ваша программа начиная с этого момента. ...

*Здесь я написал: "Зато авторы компиляторов знают: на всех популярных платформах из переменной будет прочитано случайное значение." И мне немедленно привели пример, когда clang просто выкинул обращение к неинициализированной переменной.*

... Тут у вас есть выбор: или вы следуете стандарту (нормально), или убеждаетесь что компилятор переваривает ваш код в соответствии с вашими ожиданиями (тоже нормально, если вы знаете что делаете, и проверили на всех компиляторах, которые вам нужны, и со всеми флагами компиляции, которые вам нужны, и проверили получившийся ассемблерный код и **лучше так не делайте, это не нормально**).

Comment: Можно и без нуля. Просто пустые скобки.

Comment: С каких пор  "Стандарт прямо запрещает читать не инициализированные данные"?

Comment: Цитата из стандарта: """
12) If **no initializer** is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object with **automatic** or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an **indeterminate value**, ... If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the **behavior is undefined** except in the following cases: ...
"""

Comment: @EOF, люблю чтобы с нулём. Так немного яснее и с C совместимо.

Comment: ТС может подумать, что `int a[size] = {1};` заполнит массив единицами. Ну и UB - это не запрет:)

Comment: "на всех популярных платформах из переменной будет прочитано случайное значение" - голословное утверждение. [Контрпример](https://ideone.com/grRqJe).

Comment: Ваш контрпример не совсем контрпример. Строго говоря мы извлекаем из одной переменной разные случайные значения. Но идею я понял.

Comment: @Джонни Кэтсвилл, спасибо! Мои знания устарели.